# Cmder - 'eval' command is not recognized

Tags: bash, cmder

```
λ eval
'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Just downloaded it for Windows 10.

Comment: What would you expect `eval` to be on a Windows box?

Comment: They're following instructions that assume a Linux machine (and a Linux machine with the Bash shell, specifically). When someone just tells you out of nowhere "run this eval command" and they don't even specify this crucial detail, you get confused.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `bash` first to get into a bash shell. Then `eval` will work just fine.

Comment: do you know how to exit bash in cmder?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl + d`? (`exit` actually also works for me)

Comment: This definitely should be mentioned here: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: this doesn't work on windows...

Comment: How to get into a bash shell?

Answer (score 63):

If you just want to add ssh-key to ssh-agent, use the below command.

```
start-ssh-agent.cmd
```

This will add default private keys such as id_rsa

Comment: This is the thing that worked for me! eval did not but frustrate me

Answer (score 4):

If You are using windows 10 and VS code, You can use git Bash in terminal - for me it worked.

Comment: Does not work for me in VS code; error: `Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore` Presumably one requires WSL or WSL2 plus an installed distro per error.

Answer (score -1):

Open your appilcation git bash,.. it is like cmd, but from git local,  and you can run command eval

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNYxs.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).